# "Page fetch error Failed: Redirect error" in Search Console

Tags: google-search-console, redirects

We have a page with the address: (`https://example.com/song/delgiri`)

I solved this redirect problem and it is completely green in WooRank!
[image: WooRank result]

**Now**

We have prepared four pages for Google Search Console.

1. (`https://example.com/song/delgiri`) => [image: click to show result in Search Console]
2. (`http://example.com/song/delgiri`) => [image: click to show result in Search Console]
3. (`https://www.example.com/song/delgiri`) => [image: click to show result in Search Console]
4. (`http://www.example.com/song/delgiri`) => [image: click to show result in Search Console]

> When you open all four address modes, you see that there is no problem

What's Google's problem with my page?

I will show you the complete error in the photo.
[image: click for show full result]

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: "I solved this redirect problem" - What redirect _problem_ did you solve?

Comment: @MrWhite I solved WooRank redirect problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All three URL variations of your page are redirecting properly to the canonical version. It doesn't look like there is an actual problem with your site.

Google is only going to index one of those four URLs. Google doesn't index URLs that redirect. So no matter what you do, three of those URLs are going to reported in Google Search Console as "not indexed."

When GSC reports "URL is unknown to Google" that means that there are no links to the URL and Googlebot has never had to crawl it. Since these URLs just redirect to the canonical version, that it a good thing. You don't want Googlebot doing extra crawling just to see redirects.

The reported redirect error is slightly more worrying. However, from what I can test, your URL is redirecting properly now.  if you recently changed the redirect it could take Google a few weeks or even a few months to clear an error.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You relieved my mind